# I am unable to send out Whatsapp messages

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am not able to send out any more messages while using Whatsapp. I found that there wasn't anything wrong with my phone, just the app alone was not working. What is wrong with the application?

Comment: Please read the "how to ask a good question" section of Android Enthusiasts and edit your question to bring them up to its guidelines. http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you send WhatsApp message on different WiFi/mobile data?

Answer (score 1):

On 25-26 January 2016, WhatsApp had a problem with their server.

From [Africanews - WhatsApp faces brief technical problems](http://www.africanews.com/2016/01/26/whatsapp-facing-brief-technical-problems-since-january-25/),

> Messaging application, WhatsApp, has been facing intermittent technical disruptions worldwide since Monday, January 25.
>
> ...
>
> The first set of technical problems were recorded in countries including Japan, India, Malaysia, Colombia and the United States which began around 0200 GMT.

From [MalaysianDigest - Whatsapp Was Down And There Was Chaos](http://malaysiandigest.com/frontpage/29-4-tile/591763-whatsapp-was-down-and-there-was-chaos.html),

> Popular social messaging app, WhatsApp went down this morning, leaving users worldwide frustrated.
>
> ...
>
> The server, which is used by more than 900 million users worldwide reportedly, went down at around (26 January) 10.00am local (Malaysia) time.
>
> Malaysians were not spared by the outage as seen by the flood of complaints seen on social media, Facebook and Twitter.

Lastly, my friend also had the same problem at the time you posted this question.